# VBAでバブルソートのアルゴリズムが実行できない：インデックスが有効範囲にありません

Tags: vba

以下の画像の通りにしたいんです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

それから、データは

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上にある画像のようにA1-100に並べてあります。

そのために、このコード：

```
Sub specialSort()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim inc As Integer
    Dim randomData(100) As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    For n = 1 To 100
        randomData(n) = Cells(n, 1).Value
    Next
    For i = 1 To n - 1
        For j = n To i + 1 Step -1
            If randomData(j - 1) > randomData(j) Then
                Dim tmp As Integer
                tmp = randomData(j - 1)
                randomData(j - 1) = randomData(j)
                randomData(j) = tmp
            End If
        Next
    Next
    For inc = 1 To 100
        Cells(inc, 3).Value = randomData(inc)
    Next
End Sub
```

を作りました。

しかし、なぜか実行するときエラーが出ました↓

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

誰か助けてくださると幸いです。

Comment: ちなみにフローチャート部分は[応用情報技術者平成25年秋期 午前問9](https://www.ap-siken.com/kakomon/25_aki/q9.html)に出てきた図のようですね。

Comment: @kunifそう見えるんですね。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windowsではない環境かあるいは制限か何かあるユーザーか使い方をやっているのでしょうか？
エラー発生時にはこんなダイアログが出てデバッグをクリックするとデバッガに移れると思うのですが。
[image: エラーダイアログ]

で、デバッガで停止時の場所とか各変数を見ると直ぐにわかると思いますが、以下の部分を終了した時点で`n`の値が`101`になっています。

```
    For n = 1 To 100
        randomData(n) = Cells(n, 1).Value
    Next
```

そうすると、次の内側の`For`ループの最初で`j`が`101`になり、次の行の`randomData(j)`が`randomData(101)`ということになって配列のインデックス範囲外を指定したことになり、エラーになるわけです。

```
    For i = 1 To n - 1
        For j = n To i + 1 Step -1
            If randomData(j - 1) > randomData(j) Then
```

上記の入れ子になっているそれぞれの`For`ループの`n`を使っている部分を数値そのものに変えるか、`n`の`For`ループが終わって`i`,`j`の`For`ループが始まる前に`n = 100`と再設定すれば動作するでしょう。

Comment: はい、Macでやっていました。ご回答ありがとうございます。本当に助かりました！