# VBAのセルの値と同じ名前のシート名をセットするとインデックスが有効範囲にありませんとエラーになる

Tags: vba

一覧表のA列のセルの値（確認用No）と同じ名前のシートにデータを自動転記したい。

処理中の対象レコードが、どのシートに転記されるのかを判定するコードを書いたがインデックスが有効範囲にありませんとエラーになってしまう。

```
Set wstNo = Worksheets(.Cells(r, "A").Value)                             '確認Noと同じシート名をセット
```

上記の行がエラーとなる。（インデックスが有効範囲にありません）
セルの値と同じ名前のシートはすでにある状態です。

```
Dim wstweb As Worksheet                                                            '「webアンケート」シート用オブジェクト変数
Dim wstNo As Worksheet                                                            '各確認用Noシート用オブジェクト変数
    
Dim lngERow As Long                                                                 
  
Dim r As Long
    
Set wstweb = Worksheets("webアンケート")
With wstweb
        lngERow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row                               
        
'すべての集計元データを処理
For r = 2 To lngERow
    Set wstNo = Worksheets(.Cells(r, "A").Value)                             '確認Noと同じシート名をセット
            With wstNo
                wstNo.Cells(2, "B") = wstweb.Cells(r, "B")                                '何歳
            End With
Next
End With
```

Comment: エラー発生時にデバッガに入れば、何が対象か・どういう値が原因か、と言ったことを調べられるのでは？ [調査例](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/74116/26370) あるいは他の人が簡単に調べられるようにしたサンプルデータを(必要ならばVBAも簡略化して)提示してみてください。

Comment: ちなみにこの辺の記事がヒントになるかも。[VBA セルの値と同じ名前のシートにデータを補填するやり方を教えてください](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/9638561.html), [セルの値から新規にシートを作成する。ただし既にセルの値と同じ名前のシートがある場合には作成しない。](https://teratail.com/questions/241578), [セルの値と同じ名前のシートをアクティブにするには？](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/2335370.html)